# UItextview scrolling horizontally and vertically

Tags: xcode, swift3, uitextview

UItextview scrolls horizontally and vertically at the same time.
is there any way to disable scrolling in horizontal way and enable scrolling to the vertical way ?

thank you

Comment: use direction lock property..

Comment: would you provide for me an example how to do it ?

Comment: just check properties , there is property named direction lock..

Comment: it is UIscrollView not UItextView .

Answer (score 0):

Text view itself is a subclass of scroll view. Check its properties once.[image]